# Is it possible to convert a standard PHP based widget integrated with google maps API to a flash based widget?

Tags: widget

Is it possible to convert a standard PHP based widget integrated with google maps API to a flash based widget? If yes, what are the ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect it will generally be a manual process, because the code styles are so different, code-to-code conversion would be likely to be difficult/fragile/error-prone.  The only automatic way that I could conceive of is a html-to-flash-ui conversion, which would get you a static look or prototype to start with, but wouldn't help you in the creation of the active/reactive/dynamic elements of the new flash widget.

A [quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=html+to+flash+converter&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) brings up a few paid references to html to flash conversion, as well as a few pages mentioning some libraries that might be worth pursuing, if just as a shortcut to creating a prototype that you would have to refine: 
http://drawlogic.com/2008/01/11/as3-flash-to-html-conversion-library-htmlwrapper/
and here:
http://osflash.org/flashml

Since there is one free library, there may quite likely be others as well.